# Reading a Text File that has XML data C#

Tags: c#

How do you read a text file that has XML Data?

Inside my text file:

```
<Books>
    <Book>
        <Author>John Doe</Author>
        <Title>Hello World</Title>
    </Book>
</Books>
```

Comment: `XDocument.Load(filename);`.

Comment: What would be your intention to read the data ? Do you want to query the Xml or mere display it somewhere ?

Comment: I would like to query the XML and parse the data.